# Create child model n times in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say I have a `User` & `Bonus` models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bonuses
end

class Bonus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

IE I want to create `n` bonuses with same params for user. The simplest way is:

```
n.times { u.bonuses.create!(params) }
```

But this will trigger `n` transactions and can be quiet slow for browsing if `n` is relatively big.

How can I create all this bonuses just in one transaction through activerecord (not raw sql)?

Answer (score 2):

`create` method allow an array of hashes as argument. To make it in one transaction, wrap it `transaction` block:

```
 $> attributes = Hash[:title, "foo", :about, "bar"]
 $> a = User.last
```

Without transaction:

```
 $> a.bonuses.create((1..6).map{ attributes })
      (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO 
   .......
   (11.2ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO 
   .......
   (6.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO
   ....... 
   (6.9ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO 
   .......
   (6.8ms)  COMMIT
```

With transaction:

```
 $> User.transaction { a.bonuses.create((1..6).map{ attributes }) }
 # a.bonuses.transaction { a.bonuses.create((1..6).map{ attributes }) }
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO 
   ..............
  SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO 
   ..............
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO 
   ..............  
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO 
   ..............  
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO 
   ..............
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO 
  (12.8ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: I think that's more `kiss` method than yours :)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30816734/2926641

Comment: i just provide an answer for your question, `(1..6).map{ attributes }` do same as `Array.new(n){params}` but `User.transaction { ... }` do it in transaction block.

Comment: btw, if i right remember [ActiveRecord Import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) does the same things, build a one **huge** query with many **INSERT** into db as like with transactions.

Comment: yes, so it will fasterize transaction this way. Спасибо за помощь в любом случае

Comment: там есть кнопочка для спасибо зелёная =).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [ActiveRecord Import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem:

```
bonuses = n.times.map { u.bonuses.build(params) }.flatten
Bonus.import(bonuses)
```

It will perform only one operation to the database. I don't know if it will copy or it will make a big insert, but this is a lot faster than using the normal AR capabilities.

Comment: Good idea, but this isn't pure AR :( . I don't think that's a good way to require a whole gem for this small operation. Let's wait another solutions

Answer (score 0):

the `create` method accepts array. you can create an array with the params and pass that into the `create` method. 
for example:

```
u.bonuses.create!(Array.new(n){params})
```

Hope that'll help.

Comment: It will be only one transaction but N inserts anyway.

Comment: this doesnt wrap all insert in one transaction.

Comment: Yep. You're right. I thought it was because of the output from my console. This only does a `map` over elements and calls `create!` again.

Comment: I think that method is the best across all others, but it hasn't power that I need